# ng-init overriding ng-model in the select options (plunker added)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

https://plnkr.co/edit/RgGzgGkBPaxvKHNE688K?p=preview

In the above example,I am hard coding the select options and initializing to the color 'red' via ng-init attribute. I wanted to show the color 'red' default on page load.

```
 <select ng-model="mycolor" ng-init="mycolor = 'red'">
      <option>red</option>
      <option>green</option>
    </select>
```

In the controller, I updated 'mycolor' to 'green' but the selectbox still shows 'red' because  of ng-init attribute. ( I am doing this because mycolor will be retrieved from the backend)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mycolor = 'green';
});
```

How to tackle this? In short what I wanted to achieve is, I want to show red color default value in the select box on page load  and if any change happens to mycolor in the backend it should be overridden to the new color. In my case it is green.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

`<select ng-model="mycolor" ng-init="mycolor = mycolor || 'red'">`

So the `mycolor` model will be set to itself if there is a value, otherwise default to `'red'`.

See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SQGYqLzfnmFR8snGRGEB?p=preview). I have a timeout of 5 seconds to change the color to blue to simulate a backend change as an example.

Comment: From the [**docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) of `ngInit` directive: **"There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat"**.. **"you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope."** Use `ng-init` in `ng-options` is a really bad practice.

Comment: @developer033 for sure and I agree that we can do this in the controller. But in this case, since the options were hardcoded in the template and not defined as an array in the controller I thought it would be better the keep the default value close to where the option values are defined, which is in the template.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that ngInit is a  directive and the angular life is basically

1. compile
2. controller
3. pre-link
4. post-link

and therefor you cant "override" something in the controller upon a directive (unless its specially uses compile).

it would seem more logical to put watchers on whatever need change and the the watchers callback change `'mycolor'`

Comment: then what is the alternate way of setting the default value on page load  instead of ng-init and able to achieve my goal.

Comment: the controller is your "page load", and as said you need watchers, see $scope.$watch